# mySQL Query WHERE... OR... Shortcut

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is there a shortcut for writing the following mySQL query? I am looking for a shorthand to compress

```
SELECT * FROM `listings` where `bedroom` = 1 OR `bedroom` = 2
```

because I want to make it easier to dynamically build a mySQL query in PHP. Something like `WHERE bedroom = 1, 2` because the numbers that I am getting from PHP is in an array `bedroom[1] = 1, bedroom[2] = 1`.

```
SELECT * FROM `listings` where `bedroom` = 1 OR `bedroom` = 2;
```

And because I am using Codeigniter, some shortcut for this in Active Record will be great too!

Comment: you mean like `where bedroom < 2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand very well what you're asking; do you need a shorter query?
If so, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE bedroom IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

With ActiveRecord:

```
$this->db->from("listings")->where_in("bedroom",bedroom)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IN` syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM `listings` where `bedroom` IN (1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
SELECT * FROM `listings` where `bedroom` in (1,2);
```